# How to remove conditions from WHERE clause if parameters are NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, plpgsql

I'm passing 2 parameters to a PL/pgSQL function. Here's the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 = param1 
  AND col2 = param2
```

Both parameters can be NULL, in which case the respective expression should be removed from the `WHERE` clause.

How can I do that? With `IF` conditions?

Comment: Is the function written in `plpgsql` (as opposed to plain SQL, or one of the other pluggable languages)?

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is doing the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 = param1 
  AND (param2 is null or col2 = param2);
```

This is not removing the AND condition, but should make the unimportant in case of param2 is null. So not clearly answering your question but going around... ;)

Comment: i've modified the question.Can anyone answer that too.

Comment: apply what you have learned at this one. `WHERE (param1 is null or col1 = param1) AND (param2 is null or col2 = param2)`. Of course this would return everything if both a null. Maybe thinking about valid default values at this point?

Comment: Beware. The `IS NULL` leads to a full scan table access.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest (though probably not the most efficient) way is to handle the null inside the SQL statement itself, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 = param1 
AND (param2 IS NULL OR col2 = param2)
```

This by-passes the clause for all rows if the parameter is null.

Or with this trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 = param1 
AND col2 = COALESCE(param2, col2)
```

When `param2` is `NULL`, the condition is equivalent to `col2 = col2`, which will always be true as long as `col2` doesn't itself contain `NULL` values.

A quick test using hard-coded values rather than a function parameter gave me the same query plan for both approaches - the `OR` and `COALESCE` parts are seemingly optimised away before planning the query, so it's as though the second `AND` were indeed being conditionally removed.

Comment: +1 but note that coalesce isn't a good idea, because it won't use an index if one is available whereas the first variation will.

Comment: @Denis I just did some testing with a hard-coded `NULL` or string in place of `param2`, and got identical query plans for both strategies. Since it's constant for all rows, the first becomes either `TRUE OR ...` or `FALSE OR ...`, which can be optimised away, and the second becomes `COALESCE(NULL, col2)` or `COALESCE('known value', col2)`, which can be replaced by `col2` and `'known value'` before planning the query.

Comment: actually, `col2 = col2` will not always be true. If `col2` could contain null values, this condition could be `unknown`, so this method not only won't use index, but it also could return wrong results

Comment: @RomanPekar Good point about NULL values of `col2`; I'll add a note about that.

Comment: The first query can be better for use inside PL/pgSQL - the planer will create 2 different plans and will chose one on execution time.

Answer (score 6):

A simple `(param1 IS NULL OR col1 = param1)` takes care of this, as has been answered already.

To **actually remove** any or all NULL conditions, you need **dynamic SQL**. You can build your statement in the client conditionally or you can create a plpgsql (or any other procedural language) function to take care of it. This approach may result in superior query plans when dealing with complex queries.

#### [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) function

The tricky parts are:

- to deal with NULL values and empty strings properly in string concatenation
- to deal with variable data types while avoiding possible SQL injection

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_conditional_where(_param1 int  = NULL
                                             , _param2 text = NULL
                                             , _param3 date = NULL)
  RETURNS SETOF tbl AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _where text :=
      concat_ws(' AND '
        , CASE WHEN _param1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col1 = $1' END
        , CASE WHEN _param2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col2 = $2' END
        , CASE WHEN _param3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col3 = $3' END);   
   _sql text := 'SELECT * FROM tbl';
BEGIN

IF _where <> '' THEN
   _sql := _sql || ' WHERE ' || _where;
END IF;

-- debug output
RAISE NOTICE '
 _sql:   |%|
 _where: |%|', _sql, _where;

-- execute
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql
USING $1, $2, $3;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Three examples for function call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_conditional_where();
SELECT * FROM f_conditional_where(1, 'foo');
SELECT * FROM f_conditional_where(_param3 := '2012-01-01', _param2 := 'foo');
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4528a/2)

You need to have a basic understanding of plpgsql for this. You'll find plenty of examples with ample explanation in the [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql) tag.